# Trouble building Numpy 1.6.1 on Ubuntu 9.04--no __config__.py

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy

I do research at my school by sshing into one of the machines in our lab. I do not have root access to these machines, so when I need to install new Python modules I typically build them in a local directory and modify my PYTHONPATH to point to this directory, rather than installing them to the standard directories (which I don't have permissions to). This has worked fine for several packages in the past, but with Numpy running

```
python setup.py install
```

seems to work, but there is no __config__.py file in the built directory. (The one it's supposed to import the module from) This causes the line in __init__.py

```
from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
```

to raise an ImportError. I can't figure out why __config__.py isn't being generated as Numpy seems to assume that it will be. Running the build script seems to work; it completes with no troubling error messages. I've looked but can't find any answers to this. Please help.

I am using Python 2.6.2.

Comment: If you find that you aren't getting answers here, flag your question and ask that it be sent to ubuntu.stackexchange.com (don't just ask again there, we can simply move this for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got numpy working by setting PYTHONPATH to point to the build/libXXX folder, but I was doing so to install scipy, which still demands some files as dependencies that don't exist in the either build directory I was trying. But that's another issue.